# Treeview Control becomes unresponsive - Excel 2013 64 Bit

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, activex, 32bit-64bit

**My Problem:** Treeview Control 6.0 becomes unresponsive in Excel 2013 64 Bit (Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not Found). I am able to delete the control, insert a new Treeview and it initializes fine (loads Imagelist, allows user configuration of nodes, etc.); however, once I save/close/reopen it becomes unresponsive again. This Excel tool allows users to configure a dashboard using Treeview and it worked fine (still works fine) in Excel 2007. I can include the code to initialize the Treeview control, but it is not a code issue as it works perfectly in Excel 2007.

**Attempted Solutions:** I have read through many forums and have tried numerous solutions to fix, but none have fixed the issue...

1. Running a batch file (as Admin) to unregister/re-register MSCOMCTL.OCX in the correct location
2. Deleting all .exd files from my hard drive
3. Removing/adding Common Controls reference in VBA editor
4. Deleting/Recreating the Treeview numerous times
5. Repeating above solutions in every possible order

The strangest part to me is that I can re-create the Treeview (insert, set properties), run code to initialize, and completely configure the Treeview with no issues... it only becomes unresponsive after saving/closing/re-opening. Again, the opening/closing routines worked fine in Excel 2007 so I don't think it is a code issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I need Treeview to work as it stores all of the user dashboard info (TV terminals, files to open/close, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with EXCEL 2016, 32 bit version.  EXCEL does not recognize the embedded TREEVIEW control after saving and reopening the file. (Sometimes it would work on the first save and reopen, but fail on the second.) This problem did not occur with EXCEL 2010 and earlier, same spreadsheet. Like you, I can embed a new TREEVIEW control, name with the name the macro populating uses, i.e., the name originally given to the unresponsive TREEVIEW control.  I did  not have to delete the unresponsive control like you did because EXCEL did not recognize it.  You can check this by going to Develop tab and activating the properties view.

Curiously, I found a couple of workarounds this bug in EXCEL:

1. When I saved the file while in Developer mode, it opened OK and the TREEVIEW control worked, but you have to run a macro to populate.  So far it works, but who knows....
2. When I embedded the TREEVIEW control in a Form, rather than directly in the spreadsheet, it saved and reopened OK, at least so far. No need to be in Developer mode or rerun the populating macro.

Good luck, maybe one of these will work for you.